# Convert inputted text into selectable button in iOS

Tags: ios

I am not sure how to correctly name the thing that I am looking for. Therefore I was not able to find an answer.

The effect I want to learn is for example used in the iMessage app when adding a recipient you can write the recipients name, then it is replaced by a clickable button and user is able to select then delete it by pressing delete key.

How can this be done?

Sample image from iMessage app:

[image: iMessage]

Comment: check out this link [WSTagsField](https://github.com/whitesmith/WSTagsField)

Comment: There are a lot of available, please have a look on this url. https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=tags